# Quarks and anti-quarks forming particles

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter, quarks

As I know, when particles and anti-particles come close, they anihilate. So somthing caused me a big trouble : how can particle formed by quarks and anti-quarks can exist? I've just found some mesons that are formed with quarks and anti-quarks like $\pi , D\text{ and }J/\Psi$ mesons (I'm sure that there are other). How can quarks and anti-quarks form particles if they anihilate?

Comment: My answer was false... However, in [mesons](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9son) (sorry, french), you see a great difference of lifetime ("durée de vie"). For instance the $J/\Psi = =c\bar c$ has a  $10^{-20}$ s lifetime, while all the $D$-particles (with only one charm quark) have a $10^{-13}$ s lifetime)). So these kinds of particles are very instable

Comment: Thanks, I got it now, from the answe of Will, they only anihilate after a certain time but they exist until... Et tkt je suis français ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is effectively the same as the following question:
[How do $\pi^0$ particles exist?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/how-do-pi0-particles-exist)
I hope this helps.