# Penning trap with positrons: observing annihilations?

Tags: electrons, antimatter, protons

Has a single positron been deliberately put into contact with an electron to observe the results? If so, does the annihilation occur only when the two particles "touch" or is the definition of where two such particles are not really allow for actual contact?

Have we seen what happens when a positron touches a proton or is this not even possible to cause because they have the same charge?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/236/123208

Comment: Your 2nd question is only vaguely related to your 1st one, and should probably be asked separately.